# Потребление boost ConstBufferSequence

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

Несколько буферов объединяются в [ConstBufferSequence](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ConstBufferSequence.html):

```
    std::array<char, 128> b0 = {0};
    std::array<char, 128> b1 = {0};
    std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer> bufs;
    bufs.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(b0));
    bufs.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(b1));
```

Необходимо получить потоковое чтение всех буферов, как если бы это был один непрерывный буфер (как минимум нужна функция чтения порции заданного размера с возвратом реально прочитанного количества байт).

Пока это делается тривиально - путем обхода всех буферов и копирования содержимого в отдельный буфер с которым идет дальнейшая работа (получается лишнее копирование).

В исходниках буста есть `boost::asio::detail::consuming_buffers`, который используется, например, в `boost::asio::write`, для обхода всех буферов. Т.е. на вход `boost::asio::write` можно подавать [ConstBufferSequence](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ConstBufferSequence.html) из нескольких буферов, которые будут использованы последовательно.

Официального способа использования ConstBufferSequence для чтения пока не нашел. Стоит ли велосипедить код для этого, или все-таки есть trueway?

Comment: в смысле "копировать"?

Comment: @strangeqargo скопировать код шаблона boost::asio::detail::consuming_buffers себе в проект. Хотя там довольно много зависимостей получается.

Comment: забей и используй бусты как стандартную зависимость, ты чево

Comment: @strangeqargo не хочется привязываться к конкретной реализации буста, это все таки внутренний, недокументированный класс, т.е. в теории может измениться в дальнейшем.

Comment: сделай враппером, и я сомневаюсь, что consuming_buffers куда-нибудь уйдут в будущем, скорее всего кто-нибудь уже успел их внедрить так, что они стали важной зависимостью. Олсо (чисто из интереса) ты точно все прочитал в этом (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/buffers.html) мануале? я про `consume()` и т.д.